# Using N-D interpolation with a generic rank?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, interpolation

I'm looking for an elegant way of useing `ndgrid` and `interpn` in a more "general" way - basically for any given size of input and not treat each rank in a separate case.

Given an N-D source data with matching N-D mesh given in a cell-array of 1D vectors for each coordinate `Mesh={[x1]; [x2]; ...; [xn]}` and the query/output coordinates given in the same way (`QueryMesh`), how do I generate the `ndgrid` matrices and use them in the `interpn` without setting a case for each dimension?

Also, if there is a better way the define the mesh - I am more than willing to change.

Here's a pretty obvious, conceptual (and NOT WORKING) schematic of what I want to get, if it wasn't clear

```
Mesh={linspace(0,1,10); linspace(0,4,20); ... linsapce(0,10,15)};
QueryMesh={linspace(0,1,20); linspace(0,4,40); ... linsapce(0,10,30)};
Data=... (whatever)
NewData=InterpolateGeneric(Mesh,QueryMesh,Data);


function NewData=InterpolateGeneric(Mesh,QueryMesh,Data)
    InGrid=ndgrid(Mesh{:});
    OutGrid=ndgrid(QueryMesh{:});
    NewData=interpn(InGrid{:},Data,OutGrid{:},'linear',0.0)
end
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. For example you don't need to create ndgrid . You can use : `NewData=interpn(Mesh{:},Data,OutGrid{:},'linear',0.0);` Also elements of `OutGrid` don't necessarily need to be of ndgrid format. They just need to be of the same size.

Comment: I'm sorry that the question was not clear enough, however @Cris Luengo has already written the solution I was looking for, so I don't think additional editing is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is how to get multiple outputs from this line:

```
OutGrid = ndgrid(QueryMesh{:});
```

Since `ndgrid` produces as many output arrays as input arrays it receives, you can create an empty cell array in this way:

```
OutGrid = cell(size(QueryMesh));
```

Next, prove each of the elements of `OutGrid` as an output argument:

```
[OutGrid{:}] = ndgrid(QueryMesh{:});
```